# VIM: Check if a file is open in current tab? window? (and activate it)

Tags: vim

In vim, you can check if a file is open in the current buffer with `bufexists`.  For a short filename (not full path), you can check if it's open using `bufexists(bufname('filename'))`.

Is there any way to check if a file is open in a *tab*?

My closest workaround is to do something like:

```
:tabdo if bufnr(bufname('filename')) in tabpagebuflist(): echo "Yes"
```

However, that's sort of pythonic pseudocode... I'm not sure how to get that to work in vim.  My goal is for an external applescript to check if a file is already open and if so go to a line in that file.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to search through different GUI windows too, but I've gathered (e.g. [Open vim tab in new (GUI) window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123424/open-vim-tab-in-new-gui-window)) that working with different GUI windows is very challenging / impossible in VIM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My impatience and good documentation got the better of me... here's the solution (greatly aided by [Check if current tab is empty in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025558/check-if-current-tab-is-empty-in-vim) and [Open vim tab in new (GUI) window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123424/open-vim-tab-in-new-gui-window)).  The source is at https://github.com/keflavich/macvim-skim

```
function! WhichTab(filename)
    " Try to determine whether file is open in any tab.  
    " Return number of tab it's open in
    let buffername = bufname(a:filename)
    if buffername == ""
        return 0
    endif
    let buffernumber = bufnr(buffername)

    " tabdo will loop through pages and leave you on the last one;
    " this is to make sure we don't leave the current page
    let currenttab = tabpagenr()
    let tab_arr = []
    tabdo let tab_arr += tabpagebuflist()

    " return to current page
    exec "tabnext ".currenttab

    " Start checking tab numbers for matches
    let i = 0
    for tnum in tab_arr
        let i += 1
        echo "tnum: ".tnum." buff: ".buffernumber." i: ".i
        if tnum == buffernumber
            return i
        endif
    endfor

endfunction

function! WhichWindow(filename)
    " Try to determine whether the file is open in any GVIM *window*
    let serverlist = split(serverlist(),"\n")

    "let currentserver = ????
    for server in serverlist
        let remotetabnum = remote_expr(server, 
            \"WhichTab('".a:filename."')")
        if remotetabnum != 0
            return server
        endif
    endfor

endfunction
```

then use like so:

```
exec "tabnext ".WhichTab('my_filename')

echo remote_foreground( WhichWindow('my_filename') )
```

or, from the command line, here's a script to go to a particular line of a file using `WhichTab`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
line="$2"

for server in `mvim --serverlist` 
do
    foundfile=`mvim --servername $server --remote-expr "WhichTab('$file')"`
    if [[ $foundfile > 0 ]]
    then
        mvim --servername $server --remote-expr "foreground()" 
        mvim --servername $server --remote-send ":exec \"tabnext $foundfile\" <CR>"
        mvim --servername $server --remote-send ":$line <CR>"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I think that would be useful `command! -nargs=1 -complete=file TN :let tab=WhichTab(<f-args>) <bar> if tab==0 <bar> :tabnew <args> <bar> :else <bar> :exe  'norm '.tab.'gt' <bar> endif` command to create a new tab only if a tab with the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I'd reply to keflavich, but I can't yet...

I was working on a similar problem where I wanted to mimic the behavior of gvim --remote-tab-silent when opening files inside of gvim.  I found this WhichTab script of yours, but ran into problems when there is more than one window open in any given tab.  If you split windows inside of tabs, then you will have more than one buffer returned by tabpagebuflist(), so your method of using the buffer number's position in the List doesn't work.  Here's my solution that accounts for that possibility.

```
" Note: returns a list of tabnos where the buf is found or 0 for none.
"               tabnos start at 1, so 0 is always invalid
function! WhichTabNo(bufNo)
    let tabNos = []
    for tabNo in range(1, tabpagenr("$"))
        for bufInTab in tabpagebuflist(tabNo)
            if (bufInTab == a:bufNo)
                call add(tabNos, tabNo)
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    let numBufsFound = len(tabNos)
    return (numBufsFound == 0) ? 0 : tabNos
endfunction
```

I think I can just return tabNos which will be an empty list that gets evaluated as a scalar 0, but I just learned vimscript and am not that comfortable with the particulars of its dynamic typing behavior yet, so I'm leaving it like that for now.

Comment: Good stuff.  I've moved macvim-skim to github: https://github.com/keflavich/macvim-skim in case you want to try and add some of this as a PR.  I'll try adding it later otherwise.

Comment: @cpstubing06 - could you update the issue at https://github.com/keflavich/macvim-skim/issues/1 with an example case so I can test your code a bit?  I've added your function to `WhichTab.vim`, but it's not used right now.